# Is there a constraint, interface or class that envelops IEnumerable or array?

Tags: arrays, .net-3.5, list

I'd like to take the following if possible and combine them:

```
public static T[] ForEach<T>(this T[] TArray, Action<T> doWhat)
    {
        foreach (var item in TArray)
        {
            doWhat(item);
        }
        return TArray;
    }
```

The above handles array, below handles lists

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> TList, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (var item in TList)
            action(item);
        return TList;
    }
```

Is there something in common that both inherit from or implement as an interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array inherits from IEnumerable.

Comment: In other words: you can already pass arrays to the 2nd version of the function.

Comment: I missed that because before I wrote the array accepting function, I had forgotten to import my namespace for this section of code.